# What's the maximum entropy for discrete distribution given mean and variance

Tags: entropy

I know for continuous distribution, given mean and variance,
it's Normal distribution.

I wonder what the distribution or the maximum entropy would be
if I constrain the mean and the variance.

I assumed differential entropy would be a intelligent guess,
but it was lower than some empirical entropy with the same variance.

So I wonder how I can determine the maximum entropy for a discrete distribution
when the mean and the variance is fixed...

for example, let's say the support is 1~100 all integers, and the mean is 61.09 and the sd is 12.89. what would be the maximum entropy? I tried the differential entropy
1/2*(1+ln(2*pi*sd^2)) = 3.97 but I found my empirical distribution has the entropy of 5.49

`28    29    33    35    36    37    38    39    41    42    43    44 
0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.015 0.010 0.005 0.005 0.005 0.015 0.020 
   45    46    47    48    49    50    51    52    53    54    55    56 
0.020 0.010 0.020 0.030 0.025 0.010 0.020 0.025 0.015 0.025 0.025 0.015 
   57    58    59    60    61    62    63    64    65    66    68    69 
0.065 0.020 0.020 0.030 0.055 0.035 0.040 0.005 0.030 0.015 0.025 0.050 
   70    71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78    79    80    81 
0.030 0.030 0.025 0.020 0.020 0.015 0.015 0.005 0.005 0.020 0.010 0.005 
   82    83    85    86    87    88    89    92 
0.015 0.015 0.010 0.005 0.005 0.010 0.005 0.005`

Related question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957680/maximum-entropy-distribution-with-given-variance

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I haven't worked out the math for this particular case.

I'd recommend reading chapter 12 of Cover & Thomas' Elements of Information Theory 2e.

Basically, to find it, you'd use Lagrange multipliers/KKT conditions (just like in the continuous case). If the multipliers exist, you have your distribution.

For what its worth, the mean constraint only gives something geometric-y.

For relating differential entropy and entropy of quantized distributions (which seems to be something you tried to do), see ch. 8 of Cover & Thomas.